# React Native - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native

I made the mistake of building my React Native project and only testing on the IOS simulator. I've tackled most of the bugs that where thrown when I finally tried to build the project in Android Studio but there are still three errors that are driving me insane.

1)

```
Error:(38, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

2)

```
Error:(41, 12) error: cannot find symbol method onRequestPermissionsResult(int,String[],int[])
```

3)

```
 Error:Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I think the first two errors are referring to this subclass in my `MainApplication.java`

```
 @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
```

Here is the rest of the file for context:

```
package com.fit.fitmobile;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

// Needed for `react-native link`
// import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
import com.calendarevents.CalendarEventsPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        // Add your own packages here!
        // TODO: add cool native modules

        // Needed for `react-native link`
//         new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage(),
            new CalendarEventsPackage(),
            new MapsPackage(),
            new CalendarEventsPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage()
    );
  }

  // Code for target SDK versions 23 and over.
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
}
```

The third error I've researched and tried debugging for 3 days now, but haven't made any progress. If anyone has any input I would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

onRequestPermissionsResult is not available for the Application class. You have to override it in the Activity class. Please check out the [docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)

Also here you can get a [sample implementation.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java#L254)